# Pre-select an option in select based on a string

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I've been searching around to see if there's some sort of equivalent function for `indexOf` but for select boxes that uses `ng-options`, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$scope.$parent.user.country = $scope.countries[0];
```

**EDIT:** I use `$parent` since the `$scope.user` object lives in the parent scope, but the select still has access to it.

But instead of `$scope.countries[0]` I need to select the option, which object's `name` property matches a string that comes from the database. So if `$scope.$parent.user.country` is equal to `"Sweden"`, this option should be pre-selected.

How can I achieve this?

This is a snippet from the JSON will creates the select box:

```
[
  {"name": "Sweden", "code": "SE"}, 
  {"name": "Switzerland", "code": "CH"}, 
  {"name": "Syrian Arab Republic", "code": "SY"}
]
```

This is the select box:

```
<select ng-model="user.country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some testing I found a solution which works, I managed to do so with @sq1020's answer as a foundation:

```
var index;

$scope.$parent.user.country = $scope.countries[$scope.countries.map(function(country, i) {

  if (country.name === $scope.$parent.user.country.name) {
    index = i;
    return i;
  }
})[index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just set `$scope.user.country` to the option whose name is equal to `$scope.$parent.user.country`.

```
$scope.user.country = $scope.countries.filter(function(country) { 
    return country.name === $scope.$parent.user.country;
})[0]
```

Note that filter returns an array so make sure you just get the first item.

Comment: You're missing a ) after the last }, but still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I think it should work. After you put in the missing parenthesis, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also it's $scope.$parent.user.country that needs to be set but I even changed that but nothing gets pre-selected.

Comment: $scope.$parent.user.country becomes undefined after the filter. Also the filter returns an empty array.

Comment: You said "$scope.$parent.user.country is equal to "Sweden"", so why would you be setting it? That doesn't make sense. You need to pre select $scope.user.country because you ng-model is set to "user.country".

Comment: Because $scope.user lives in the parent scope, not the scope of the controller which it's being set in. But the select still have access to it.

Comment: You should create a plunkr to make your problem more clear.

Comment: Managed to solve it by altering your solution a bit :) I'll show you how I did it.

Comment: Check out my answer, not sure if you were the one downvoting the question but I evened your answer out since it helped me. If you tweak your answer a bit I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Any of you red docs??

```
<label>Check me to select: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected"></label><br/>
<select aria-label="ngSelected demo">
  <option>Hello!</option>
  <option id="greet" ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
</select>
```

ng-selected='selected' <- word selected in apostrophes points to $scope.selected. Just put your selection value there.

Here you have docs link: [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

Here you have my example.
I bring you my whole javascript with reading 4 selects from database dependant on selection in each other and after this you will see my whole jade part of this code. You may copy this sollution with your names.

```
.controller('datatableRelationController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.relations = [];
        $scope.tables = [];


        $scope.firstTableColumns = [];
        $scope.secondTableColumns = [];
        //display menu with tables
        $http.get('/api/datatable/list/')
            .success(function (json_data, status, headers, config) {
                for (key in json_data) {
                    var fields = json_data[key]['fields'];
                    $scope.tables.push({name: fields['name']});
                }
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                Materialize.toast("Błąd pobierania tabel", 2000);
            });

        $scope.addRelation = function () {
            var data = {
                source_table: $scope.firstTable.name,
                source_column: $scope.firstTableSelectedColumn.name,
                dest_table: $scope.secondTable.name,
                dest_column: $scope.secondTableSelectedColumn.name,
                relation_type: 'normal'
            };
            apiPOST('/api/relation/add/', data, $http)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    Materialize.toast('Relacja dodana.', 2000);
                    $scope.relations = [];
                    $scope.tables = [];


                    $scope.firstTableColumns = [];
                    $scope.secondTableColumns = [];
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    Materialize.toast('Błąd dodawania relacji.', 2000)
                });
        };

        var getColumns = function (tableName, destination) {
            $http.get('/api/worktable/fields/get/' + tableName)
                .success(function (json_data, status, headers, config) {
                    var fields = json_data[0];
                    for (key in fields) {
                        destination.push({name: fields[key]});
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    Materialize.toast("Błąd pobierania kolumn z tabeli", 2000);
                });
        }

        $scope.firstTableChange = function (firstTable) {
            getColumns(firstTable.name, $scope.firstTableColumns);
        };

        $scope.secondTableChange = function (secondTable) {
            getColumns(secondTable.name, $scope.secondTableColumns);
        };
    }
]);
```

JADE PART:

```
        .row
            .col.l5.m6.s12.offset-l1
                .form
                    .input-field
                        select.browser-default(ng-model="firstTable", ng-change="firstTableChange(firstTable)", ng-options="table.name for table in tables", material-select)
                            option(value="", disabled, ng-selected) Wybierz pierwszą tabelę
                div(ng-show="firstTable || secondTable")
                    .form(ng-show="firstTable")
                        .input-field
                            select.browser-default(ng-model="firstTableSelectedColumn", ng-change="firstTableSelectedColumn", ng-options="column.name for column in firstTableColumns", required, material-select)
            .col.l5.m6.s12
                .form
                    .input-field
                        select.browser-default(ng-model="secondTable", ng-change="secondTableChange(secondTable)", ng-options="table.name for table in tables", material-select)
                            option(value="", disabled, ng-selected) Wybierz drugą tabelę
                div(ng-show="firstTable || secondTable")
                    .form(ng-show="secondTable")
                        .input-field
                            select.browser-default(ng-model="secondTableSelectedColumn", ng-change="secondTableSelectedColumn", ng-options="column.name for column in secondTableColumns", required, ng-show="secondTable", material-select)
        .row
            .col.s12.center-align
                button.btn.orange.lighten-2.weaves-effect.white-text(ng-click="addRelation()") Zastosuj
```

Comment: This doesn't help me at all unfortunately.

Comment: I ll give you better tip then in a moment.

Comment: I have more than one select box so just setting $scope.selected won't do anything, also your answer doesn't cover how I would match the existing string with an option object in the select.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do this

`<select ng-model="user.country" ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries"></select>`

And it should work

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.